# .HTACCESS, problema al abrir una pagina desde un servidor remoto

Tags: php, .htaccess

Estoy montando a un servidor remoto una pagina web creada con `PHP` con `Modelo-Vista-Controlador`. En mi servidor local (`XAMPP`) funciona perfecto, la URL de esta es `http://localhost/pagina` y este es mi codigo de `.htaccess`

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)$ index.php?c=$1&a=$2&id=$3&estado=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)$ index.php?c=$1&a=$2&id=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ index.php?c=$1&a=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)$ index.php?c=$1 [L]
```

Cuando monto el `.htaccess` al servidor remoto solo me reconoce la pagina de inicio `http://pagina.com`.  Cuando trato de ingresar a alguna interna esta me arroja el `error 404` y no reconoce la pagina.  Muchas gracias.

Comment: Como es la url que estás ingresando y falla. Por otro lado tené en cuenta que los RewriteCond aplican solo al primer  RewriteRule. Si queres que esas condiciones apliquen a todas las reglas los tenes que repetir por regla

Comment: por ejemplo, http://pagina.com/tarea